# traffic of AF41 marking under interface

Tags: router, qos, huawei

I have used port-queue commands most of the time to check traffic status under BE, EF, AF4. But I haven't found command to check for AF41 to AF42 on Huawei VRP or cisco IOS.
How can check traffic of AF41 marking under interface?

Normally I use "`display port-queue statistics interface interface_name outbound`" 
It displays only AF4 and other queue traffic, but no statistics of AF41 or subclass. Please suggest.

Many Thanks